# Posting any text with ampersand "&" back to web service is causing issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am posting text with ampersand "&" back to web service and it is causing issues in my Objective C application.

I have to escape it somehow.

Any ideas?... I am very new to Objective C and iPhone programming at the moment...

Comment: Have you tried using the %26 encoding?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp & http://www.doublecloud.org/2011/09/escaping-characters-for-soap-xml-late-but-here/..I could find this by googling.. you couldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you try to pass some values in the `URL` and the value contains `&` which is used to separate parameters in the `URL`, hence the web server spilts the content into parts wherever it encounters an `&` rather than taking it as a single continuos value.
You can url encode the string to resolve the problem.

```
NSString *valueToSubmit = @"This is my value which contains & in it.";
NSString *urlEncodedString  = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)valueToSubmit,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
NSLog(@"Non-Encoded: %@ \n Encoded: %@",valueToSubmit,urlEncodedString];
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Non-Encoded: This is my value which contains & in it.
URL Encoded: This%20is%20my%20value%20which%20contains%20%26%20in%20it.
```

Comment: You need to replace the `&` with `%26`.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are posting something like "bread & butter" then what you see in your web service is missing the & and possibly a few characters after it or even a weird character in its place. Try replacing & with `&amp;` So in the example above, you'd post "bread  `&amp;`butter". You will find similar problems if you try to send a < or > and a few other characters. If you google NSString HTML escape you will find Objective C categories that can help you do this.

For an URL like www.mysite/foo&bar.html you would want to replace they & with %26 So www.mysite/foo%26bar.html. The same would be true in a query string. Replace the & with %26

Comment: The problem is with URL character escaping, not HTML character escaping.